# How to convert a tuple to a simple number?

Tags: python

I have values that looks like this:  [1287963] . They are extracted from a dictionary:

```
for key, val in plots[key].items():
        print(val,count)
```

I need to display it like this `1287963`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As val appears to be a list, access to its first elements (i.e. your number) val[0]. This should return your number.

Comment: It might be a good idea to check `len(val)==1` first, unless you can be absolutely sure that the values *never* contain more than one element.